# Need to add a number to a pageref in word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, worksheet-function, page-numbers

I am trying to add a number to a pageref in word.

I have a bookmark at a certain page, and 17 pages later I need to restart page numbering from that page, but there's a section in between. I'm trying to use the formula field, something like this:

```
=SUM(17;{PAGEREF(MY_BOOKMARK)})
```

But I get syntax error for the curly braces. The [examples](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-formula-field-HP005186218.aspx) use curly braces but that page is horrible casue it doesn't show the actual code you need to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is:

```
{ =17+{ PAGEREF bookm } }
```

You have to press **ctrl** + **F9** twice to have a nested field.